# What is meant by ?? in Dart

Tags: dart

I saw this operator in [Example of Shared Preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) for Flutter plugin. And I didn't get it.

```
int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called **null-aware operator**

Meaning, if and only if `prefs.getInt('counter')` returns `null` assign `0` to it and then increment by one.

Here, you can find a great blog post about null-aware operator: http://blog.sethladd.com/2015/07/null-aware-operators-in-dart.html