# What is this unary postfix in dart/flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, postfix-notation, unary-operator

i saw this unary postfix in Dart/flutter code: `?.`

like this:

```
videoController?.dispose();
```

and i want to know how it work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great feature in Dart

meaning is **if and only if that object is not null otherwise, return null**.

Simple example:

```
void main() {
  Person p1 = new Person("Joe");
  print(p1?.getName); // Joe

  Person p2;
  print(p2?.getName); // null

  //print(p2.getName); // this will give you an error because you cannot invoke a method or getter from a null
}

class Person {
  Person(this.name);
  String name;

  String get getName => name;
}
```

There are other cool null aware operators like `??`. [Read my QnA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801706/what-is-meant-by-in-dart) to find out more about null-aware operators.

Answer (score 2):

It tests for null,

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour

"?. Conditional member access   Like ., but the leftmost operand can be null; example: foo?.bar selects property bar from expression foo unless foo is null (in which case the value of foo?.bar is null)"

Answer (score 2):

It is a ***null-aware*** operator. It is the short form of the following.

#### Code

```
 ((obj) => obj == null ? null : x.method())(object)
 // is equal to
 object?.method()
```

You can find out more [about *null-aware operators* here](http://blog.sethladd.com/2015/07/null-aware-operators-in-dart.html?m=1).

#### Explanation

*Reads as:*

- Only execute `method` if `object` is not `null`
- If `object` is `null` return `null` (otherwise evaluation from `method`)